# Singleton management implementation and thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, singleton

I have been playing around with ways to implement Singletons. I have written a little management object that allows for a easier, less code approach to writing singleton classes.

I would never use something like this in a production system for a couple of reason which lead me to my question.

With the below code - I am assuming that this implementation would/could lead to both threading issues and memory leaks? Would I be correct?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{       
    public static class SingletonManager
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, object> Objects;

        static SingletonManager()
        {
            Objects = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        public static T InstanceOf<T>(object[] ctorArgs = null)
            where T : class
        {
            var name = typeof (T).FullName;
            if (Objects.ContainsKey(name))
                return Objects[name] as T;

            var ctor = typeof (T).GetConstructors(
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.NonPublic)[0];

            var instance = ctor.Invoke(ctorArgs) as T;
            Objects[name] = instance;

            return instance as T;
        }

        public static void DisposeOf<T>()
            where T : Singleton<T>
        {
            Dispose(typeof (T).FullName);
        }

        public static void DisposeOf(Type type)
        {
            Dispose(type.FullName);
        }

        private static void Dispose(string name)
        {
            if (!Objects.ContainsKey(name)) return;

            var obj = Objects[name];
            if (obj is IDisposable)
                ((IDisposable) Objects[name]).Dispose();

            Objects.Remove(name);
        }
    }

    public class Singleton<T>
        where T : class
    {
        private static object ThreadLock = new object();

        public static T Instance(object[] ctorArgs = null)
        {
            lock (ThreadLock)
            {
                return SingletonManager.InstanceOf<T>(ctorArgs);
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeSingletonClass : Singleton<SomeSingletonClass>
    {
        public int Number;

        private SomeSingletonClass(int i)
        {
            Number = i;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var instance1= SomeSingletonClass.Instance(new object[] {1});

            var instance2 = SomeSingletonClass.Instance(new object[] { 2 });

            //Is false
            var updated = instance1.Number == 2;

            instance2.Number = 99;

            //Is true
            var equals = instance1.Number == instance2.Number;

            //Is true
            var refEquals = ReferenceEquals(instance1, instance2);

            Debugger.Break();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a singleton manager? Singletons should be rare and are easy to implement using `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: Yes, this is true. And as I said I would never use something like this in an actual system. I was just looking through some old code today on a project that used a lot of singleton classes and wanted to have a play around with an easy implementation.

Comment: You should probably be using CodeReview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. I would avoid naming methods things like Dispose unless the object implements IDisposable.

Answer (score 3):

1. Classical singletons are very rarely a good idea. In most cases you're better off with simply creating a single instance which you pass to the code that needs it, instead of enforcing that there is only one. An IoC container will do most of that work for you.
2. An implementation of a classical singleton is quite compact, no need to simplify it further:

   ```
   public class MySingleton
   {
       private static Lazy<MySingleton> _instance = new Lazy<MySingleton>(() => new MySingleton());    
       public static MySingleton Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }

       private MySingleton()
       {

       }
   }
   ```

   At best you can save two of these lines.
3. Yes, your code is not thread safe. You'd need to put most of it in `lock` statements to fix that.
4. The consumer determining the constructor parameters is very dubious. Unless all of them are identical, you'll end up with different instances, depending on which consumer runs first.

   This violates the "single source of truth" principle and is a maintenance and debugging nightmare.
5. Your code relies on private reflection.